# Decorated function returns None

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a decorator that checks a function's argument for `int` type.

```
def check_type_int(old_function):
    def new_function(arg):
        if not isinstance(arg, int):
            print 'Bad Type'    # raise TypeError('Bad Type')
        else:
            old_function(arg)
    return new_function
```

When I run a decorated function, it returns `None` instead of an `int` value.

```
@check_type_int
def times2(num):
    return num*2

times2('Not A Number')  # prints "Bad Type"
print times2(2)         # prints "None"
```

The last line should print `4`. Can someone please spot my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you explicitly checking types like this? And why `print` rather than raising an error if the type is invalid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't `return` any value from `new_function` inside the decorator, therefore it returns `None` by default. Just change this line:

```
old_function(arg)
```

to

```
return old_function(arg)
```

Comment: actually you should pass *args not arg

Comment: Yes, I intended it to be a single argument function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37907583/2873538) by @eugeney: it would be easier if you used `return` for both cases in `if`:

```
if not isinstance(arg, int):
    return 'Bad Type'          # return 
else:
    return old_function(arg)   # return
```

And this:

```
print times2('2')                # prints Bad Type
print times2(2)                  # prints 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *args and **kwargs

```
def dec(function):
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        return function(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_f
```