# Why it is said I can not use hello() to run this code?

Tags: python

This is my code and I want to use Hello() function to run this code. I tested and they said

> hello()
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

What should I do then?

```py
def announce(f):
    def wrapper():
        print ("About to run the function...")
        f()
        print("Done with the function.")
        return 


@announce
def hello():
    print("Hello, world!")

hello()
```

Comment: fix your indentation... return wrapper should be aligned with the def wrapper and you should `result =f()` then  `return result` from inside the wrapper def

Comment: Did you assign any value to `hello`?

Comment: Possibly duplicated? [Decorated function returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37907505/decorated-function-returns-none)

Answer (score 0):

you need to return your wrapper ...

```
def announce(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print(f"About to run {func.__name__}")
        result = func(*args,**kwargs)
        print(f"Done running {func.__name__}")
        return result
    # announce returns the wrapper...
    return wrapper

@announce
def hello():
    print("Hello world!")

hello()
```